# Rails undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class

When iterating through my Items array, I am trying to print the item, along with the previous item in the array, but I am having some difficulty doing so. Each image I want to print is the same as the item name.
The code where I get my error is as follows:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
<img src="/assets/<%= item.name %>.jpeg" >
//This is where I get my error//
<img src="/assets/<%= @items[item.id - 1].name %>.jpeg" >
<% end %>
```

It prints out the error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass. However if I change the line where the error occurs to "<%= @items[item.id].class %>" it shows that the class is an Item rather than nil. Also if I hard code the number in, such as ".jpeg" >" rails correctly outputs the picture.

Comment: Log items , I bet there is a nil in there.  Your test items[item.id].class is not actually testing the with the correct index to the array.  You could try items.each_with_index do |item,i| and item = items[i] to verify it is indeed nil.  That is my guess.

Comment: what does it say if you print item.class?

Comment: The code item.class prints that it is an Item object (which I believe is what @items is an array of).

Comment: @digidigo, items.each_with_index worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see:

`@item` is NOT defined, you probably meant `@items`, and in that case, what you did won't help you either most probably because the the id on your current item has nothing to do with the index in the collection.

If instead of copy/pasting you typed that and you indeed have `@items` there, you still have the problem that `item.id - 1` is not what you mean. You probably mean:

```
<% @items.each_with_index do |item, i| %>
<% i = i - 1 %>
<img src="/assets/<%= item.name %>.jpeg" >
//This is where I get my error//
<% unless i < 0 %>
<img src="/assets/<%= @items[i].name %>.jpeg" >
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

AND if you still are getting that, then it means you have nils in your collection and you need:

```
<% @items.compact.each_with_index do |item, i| %>
<% i = i - 1 %>
<img src="/assets/<%= item.name %>.jpeg" >
//This is where I get my error//
<% unless i < 0 %>
<img src="/assets/<%= @items[i].name %>.jpeg" >
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're already iterating over the `@items` array, with each item in the variable `item`. However, there's no guarantee that the `.id` attribute on each item will correspond to its exact position in the `@items` array. If each `item` in your database has a different `.id`, then there's no guarantee that there are even that many items in your `@items` array.

For example, in this array:

```
@items = {{id: 5}, {id: 10}}
```

each item has the index `0` and `1` in the `@items` array. However, trying to find the "previous" item by doing `@items[item.id - 1]` will result in Ruby looking for an item at index `4` in the `@items` array - which doesn't exist.

---

`each_with_index` will help you solve this problem though - you can use it to get the actual index of each item in the array, instead of depending on the `.id` attribute. Something like this:

```
<% @items.each_with_index do |item, index| %>
    <img src="/assets/<%= item.name %>.jpeg" >
    <img src="/assets/<%= @items[index - 1].name %>.jpeg" >
<% end %>
```